I try to download pygame for python3.10.7 (pip version 23.3.2) and there is a problem. Earlier I can download any library but now I can't
I tried to write it like this :
pip install pygame
But  there is a problem
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E976A76D10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E976A77010>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E976A77340>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E976A774F0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /simple/pygame/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x000001E976A776A0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] Подключение не установлено, т.к. конечный компьютер отверг запрос на подключение')': /simple/pygame/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pygame (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pygame

please help me I don't know what I shoul do!
I searched the Internet, but didn't find much information about this problem

Are you using venv? If not, create one using python -m venv venv  and then activate it with ./venv/Scripts/activate  (if you are on Linux, use python3 -m venv venv and source ./venv/bin/activate) . After create and activate it, try to install pygame again

This a network issue, so unlikely solved using a venv... Have you changed anything about your network recently (i.e. moved to a new location) or are you in a "managed" network (company/institution) and your IT department might have made security changes?
